# filter Custom Post type posts by Taxonomy and Custom Field value in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a Custom Post type Listing with Custom taxonomy of 'Hotels', 'Home Stays', 'Resorts' etc.. and have a custom meta box for this Post type, that is 'City'...So What I want is I want to filter Items by Custom Taxonomy and Custom Meta Box value...for eg:- I want to get A Resort name in a particular City...Is there any body can help me with this Q...I will be more grateful if it is a Ajaxified version. I am using the Following Loop, I am getting '$inCity ' and '$searchFor' variables through a Post Request from a Previous page that Having a form with action set to a custom page template. and the Loop is in a custom page template

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
    array( 
      'post_type'  => 'listing',    
      'meta_key'    => 'directory_select',  
      'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
      'order'       => 'asc',    
      'posts_per_page' => '1',
      'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
      'meta_query'  => array(
         array(        
          'key'     => 'directory_select', 
          'value'   => $inCity )
         ),
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'find',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $searchFor,
            'operator'  => 'IN')

            )

       )
    );
```

?>